# Why does order matter for Sinusoidal paths in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

just a quick question regarding possibly how Unity2D engine compile or runtime works, or maybe something I don't understand at all, so the following code works properly:

```
pos -= Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed * transform.right;
transform.position = magnitude * pos + axis * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency);
```

However if I move the pos + axis (both are Vector3) then the pathing does not do what is expected, I was just wondering why this is the case. For example the following code would not work how I want it to:

```
pos -= Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed * transform.right;
transform.position = magnitude * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * pos + axis;
```

If anyone has any insight I'd like to know.

Thank you.

Comment: In math in general multiplication is always handled **before** addition ... you are comparing `x * a + b` (= `(x * a) + b`) with `x + a * b` (= `x + (a * b)`) which of course is not the same ...

Answer (score 1):

Unity will resolve math equations following the [`pemdas`](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html) order of operations. To clarify, it will handle everything in the order of:

1. Parathesis
2. Exponents
3. Multiplication / Division
4. Addition / Subtraction

Along with this, the order of operations are read left to right, so whatever appears on the left will be handled first, which is how the tie breakers of Addition / Subtraction and Multiplication / Division are handled.

In your example case, moving the variables as you have results in a completely different operation. For simplicity, I will substitute the vectors for whole numbers and just write out the multiplication as `vector * vector` and `vector * scalar` are just scaled vectors, so I can equally substitute all of them for ints.

```
pos = 5
axis = 3
Mathf.Sin(frequency * Time.time) = 2
magnitude = 12
```

Now substituting these values into your two equations:

```
12 * 5 + 3 * 2 (12 * 5 is handled first, next 3 * 2 and then 60 + 6 = 66)
12 * 2 * 5 + 3 (12 * 2 is handled first, next 24 * 5 and then 120 + 3 = 123)
```

Following the pemdas rule I explained above, the solutions would work out to be:

```
66
123
```

If you would like an explanation using vectors I can write one out.

Comment: this is a problem I've had, too. Sometimes, in some situations, division will happen before multiplication, when you least need it to do that way, and this can cause some oddities, with making sine waves, somehow. Even though it probably shouldn't. I've resorted to brackets (Every) (Single) (Time) to make sure things happen in the order I want.

Comment: @Confused division and multiplication do never behave the way you say ... it doesn't matter at all if you do `x / 10` or `x * 0.1` .. the result is the same .... OP's issue is rather that once it is `x + a * b` and the other time `x * b + a` which of course is not the same. When you do however `x / a * b` but you actually want `x / (a * b)` .. well, then yes .. you'll have to write it that way .. not only in code also on paper ;)

Comment: as I say, dear wonderful der super Hugo, it shouldn't go wrong. But I have seen it go wrong, particularly in the making of sine waves, in Unity. I don't know why, but my guess would be that something is getting cached and re-ordering as though brackets were used is occurring. There's more than a few oddities like this in Unity. I've used it enough to know not to trust it, ever.

Comment: @Confused, its hard to believe that the order of operations will not behave as coded in any mature programming languaje. When the outcome expected is not the one obtained, most, if not all of the time is that there is a bug in the code, or a mistake in the logic. I would say that in something such as trivial as the order if the operations  that should be the case for sure

Comment: I know. That's why it's a comment on the answer, not on the question, so as to avoid distraction from the issue in the question, and point out that any solution that might be normal in the rest of the world is not necessarily going to be the case in Unity. btw, this inside `OnAudioFilterRead` whilst using Mathf.Pi, so it might be something unique to that thread and Unity's mechanisms, and their interpretation of C# to whatever C++ backend parsing they do. It's not "C# the language", it's C# as the scripting language for Unity, in the Audio thread with their Maths library. @rustyBucketBay

Comment: ah duh, yeah that makes sense, I'm dumb.

Comment: @CameronShore Happens to everyone! Sometimes just need another set of eyes to point something out.